# GATE - Treetagger: Token.category still in English

Tags: gate

Due to some reasons, I needed to install Gate on another computer. So I needed to transfer the Gate work I had done until now on the other computer.

Everything seem to work fine. I downloaded Treetagger for french and it runs without errors popping out.

However, I don't understand why French language doesn't seem to be recognized by Gate (some words have an "Unknown" annotation) and Token.category still display the english POS and not the french POS.
For example, for a verb, I should have Token.category=VER:pres, but I get Token.category=VB.

I tried to remove the Annie POS Tagger, but the annotation doesn't work well without it.

When I execute *echo 'Appelle!' | cmd/tree-tagger-french* on command line, I get correct annotations:

```
reading parameters ...
tagging ...
Appelle VER:pres    appeler
!   SENT    !
finished.
```

I would very much appreciate any help or hint, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution after looking into the tree-tagger-french-gate file...
I had to install gawk:

```
update-alternatives --display awk (to check how the system in providing awk)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gawk (install GNU awk - the one Treetagger needs)
```

I hope this could also help someone.